# rethrowing subclass of RuntimeException

Tags: java, exception

I'm creating a general class that accepts as a parameter a list of exceptions it is willing to handle.

```
public class MyClass {
  public MyClass (List<Class<? extends RuntimeException>> exceptions) ...
  public execute() {
    try {
      justObj.call()
    } catch(RuntimeException e) {
      if exceptions.contains(e.getClass()) {...}
      else {throw e;}
    }
```

I want the thrown exception to be the original one I caught, e.g. if it was NullPointerException then I want the throw to be NullPointerException  and not RuntimeException  as it now.

Any idea how to achieve it ?

Comment: Did you try it?  If not, why not?

Comment: Thanks. I had a bug in my code that changed the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works already:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
            ((ArrayList) null).get(0);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.main(Test.java:96)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you catch a RuntimeException (or any sub class), it doesn't change the type of the object/exception.  If its a NullPointerException it will still be this type of object when you throw it again (as you have in your code)

Answer (score 0):

It will be - RuntimeException is just a reference to the original object, which will be whatever subclass of RuntimeException was originally thrown (e.g NullPointerException).